# VSCode, terminal has space after every character

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've just opened VSCode, and the terminal had changed.

It has a space after every character. I don't know what causes the problem.

How can I restore the normal output?

[image: vscode terminal]

Comment: Maybe a bad font?

Comment: Note that restarting VSCode might resolve the issue (it did in my case).

Answer (score 4):

You've entered a wrong font name or no font name

Go to settings and search up "terminal font" and on `Terminal › Integrated: Font Family`. You probably have no font entered or wrong font name. Try to enter a font like `Consolas`. Maybe you didn't download a font correctly because this usually happens.

Happy Coding!