# How to fix my problem which is raised in my VS Code in terminal section

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm not sure why there are so many spaces between the letters in the VS Code terminal.

Here I'm sharing the screenshot of the problem - 
[Problem (My VS Code terminal)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JluiB.png)

I tried changing the font and font size to fix it, but nothing worked. I want default VS Code terminal like this 
[Default VS Code Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMZf5.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70634591/9938317 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/66910984/9938317 with a simple search on SO

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you so much @rioV8 , My problem is permanently fixed now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those who wants to know the solution is -

1. First, go to the settings in VS Code.
2. Then search for "terminal font"
3. Then go to **Terminal > Integrated: Font Family**.
4. After that, just add "`Consolas`" font in the box (or any other mono space font installed).
5. Now it's done. You can check out the terminal.

Here's a screenshot.

[image: Just do this]

Happy Coding :)