# VSCode, terminal has space after every character without Font change

Tags: visual-studio-code

I sporadically have the same problem with the spaces as described in the [VSCode, terminal has space after every character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70634554/vscode-terminal-has-space-after-every-character). After restarting everything is OK again for a while. If this happens an embedded device is connected and the serial console is open and prints outputs

I expect normal display wo restart.